# How to deal with slow receivers in Netty ChannelGroup

Tags: netty

I'm using ChannelGroup to broadcast messages, sadly I haven't found solution to properly deal with possible slow receivers in the group.

Searched a lot online but still haven't figured out how to utilize the channelWritabilityChanged() or ChannelGroupFutureListener to implement my desired server behaviour: the server could keep broadcasting normal clients all the time, meanwhile don't write to slow receivers until the channel isWritable() becomes true.

The basic server channel handler looks like below:

```
public class ServerChannelHandler extends SimpleChannelInboundHandler<String> {
    private ChannelGroup group;

    @Override
    protected void messageReceived(ChannelHandlerContext ctx, String msg) throws Exception {
        BizObject bizObject = doBizLogic(msg);
        group.writeAndFlush(bizObject);
    }
}
```

Thanks very much for any help!

Answer (score 1):

I believe you shall implement yourself the logic as you described:

(pseudo code)

```
For all channel in group
   if channel.isWritable is true => immediate write and flush
   possibility 1) (difficult) else through channel.channelPipeline() get the right handler
      on future channelWritabilityChanged(), write what you need
      you need to handle various things:
        - the message to send, 
        - the possibility the writabilityChanged before your handler is ready to handle this
        - ...
   possibility 2) (easy) else add this channel in a new temporary group
call once the loop is over this group asynchronously as you did
  - group.writeAndFlush(object) in an extra thread (so totally asynchronously) 
  - with a possible extra object (shared by the caller thread and the callee) 
  if you want to know when all messages are effectively sent
```